# PDF Sharing on a Android Client

Tags: android, web-services, pdf

I wanna create an application where when i open a PDF to a particular page and a zoom position. i should be able to share the same to another client.

It will be Android Tablet with a Webserver to support it.

Can someone guide me how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is going to load, process and display PDF documents, then you need a PDF viewer component suitable for Android OS. If you are only going to generate the PDFs on a server for use in Android devices, then you need a PDF-creation component on the server. This component should create a go-to PDF action at the document-level for the document open event (see PDF reference). A PDF-compliant viewer application, such as Adobe Reader, will execute this action when the document is opened by an end-user. That is, instead of the usual first page, the viewer application will automatically navigate to the page specified in the go-to PDF action. When adding the go-to action, you can specify the page number, rectangular area on the page, and the page magnification level.

Comment: when a pdf is opened and set to a zoom and part of the page. can these parameters be retrieved too ?

Comment: If a go-to PDF action has been specified for the document-open event for an existing document, then yes it is possible to obtain the rectangle and page-fit settings of that action. PDF viewer applications read this details so they can execute the PDF action. A PDF library that can read existing PDF documents will be able to provide the rectangle and fit settings.